# Sharepoint "View in File Explorer" opens in another IE window instead of File Explorer

Tags: sharepoint-online, open-with-explorer

I have unique trouble with opening file in explorer mode. When clicked, it opens a new IE window instead of a file explorer (with no error message). I noticed that this problem only applies to one computer while the other with same settings is able to open it in file explorer.

Tried solutions:

- I have added sharepoint to trusted sites and compatibility view.
- Webclient is running
- ActiveX is enabled
- IE version 11

I've been checking around without finding similar issues. Let me know if you know to work this out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following settings:

1. Restart WebClient Service
2. Make sure you use 32-bit version of IE.
3. Make sure the “SharePoint Export Database Launcher”, “SharePoint OpenDocuments Class” and “SharePoint Stssync Handler” are enabled via IE->Tools-> Manage Add-ons.